# How to convert pandas Series to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series as se:

```
wind      yes
humidity     high
weather    sunny
temp    hot
conclusion    bad
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

And I want to convert it into a dataframe like:

```
  | weather| temp | humidity | wind | conclusion
0 | sunny | hot  | high | yes | bad
```

I've tried

```
pd.DataFrame(se)
```

but it turns out to be something else

```
wind      yes
humidity     high
weather    sunny
temp    hot
conclusion    bad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_frame` and transpose your new dataframe:

```
df = sr.to_frame(0).T
print(df)

# Output:
  wind humidity weather temp conclusion
0  yes     high   sunny  hot        bad
```

Setup

```
data = {'wind': 'yes',
        'humidity': 'high',
        'weather': 'sunny',
        'temp': 'hot',
        'conclusion': 'bad'}
sr = pd.Series(data, name=1)
print(sr)

# Output
wind            yes
humidity       high
weather       sunny
temp            hot
conclusion      bad
Name: 1, dtype: object
```